# How to categorize values in table for monthly base within year

Tags: mysql, datetime

hi I got three table columns 

vehicle_id int(11) auto_increment primary_key, 
vehicle_reg_no varchar(100) not_null, 
inp_datetime datetime not_null

I need to extract these data.

*Vehicle Register Number* **|** *January* **|** *February* **|** *March*  ....... *December* **|**  *Total*

So far I did this query but I don't get expected values.

[image]

```
SELECT COUNT(vehicle_master.vehicle_id)as countVal,
vehicle_master.vehicle_reg_no,
MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(EXTRACT(MONTH FROM vehicle_master.inp_datetime),'%m'))as monthName
FROM vehicle_master
GROUP BY  vehicle_master.inp_datetime
```

Comment: Can you use `DATE_FORMAT(vehicle_master.inp_datetime,"%M")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure of your schema, but from what I can see you could just be looking for this:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(vm01.inp_datetime,"%M") as monthName
, COUNT(*) as countVal
FROM vehicle_master vm
GROUP BY monthName

Month    | Count
------------------
January  |   10
February |   13
March    |    4
etc      |  etc
```

However, I kind of get a sense that that's not what you're trying to do, in which case this might give you an idea (or atleast this would give you the output as you've specified it above):

```
SELECT vm.vehicle_reg_no as `Vehicle Register Number`
, COUNT(mv01.*) as January
, COUNT(mv02.*) as February
, COUNT(mv03.*) as March
-- , COUNT(mv04.*) as etc
, COUNT(mv.*) as Total
FROM vehicle_master vm
LEFT JOIN vehicle_master vm01 on vm01.vehicle_id=vm.vehicle_id and vm01.vehicle_reg_no=vm.vehicle_reg_no and vm01.inp_datetime=vm.inp_datetime and DATE_FORMAT(vm01.inp_datetime,"%m") = "01"
LEFT JOIN vehicle_master vm02 on vm02.vehicle_id=vm.vehicle_id and vm02.vehicle_reg_no=vm.vehicle_reg_no and vm02.inp_datetime=vm.inp_datetime and DATE_FORMAT(vm02.inp_datetime,"%m") = "02"
LEFT JOIN vehicle_master vm03 on vm03.vehicle_id=vm.vehicle_id and vm03.vehicle_reg_no=vm.vehicle_reg_no and vm03.inp_datetime=vm.inp_datetime and DATE_FORMAT(vm03.inp_datetime,"%m") = "03" -- etc
GROUP BY vehicle_reg_no
```